# java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl@1b79d968 is closed

Tags: java, hibernate, connection

I'm learning how to use Hibernate with Servlet. And this error appeared on console:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl@1b79d968 is closed
```

I've tried to find the previous solution but there isn't any. I tried to use session.close() but it didn't  work. The browser stuck on loading. And when I restarted the tomcat, it can't response for a while.

Please help me. Thank in advance.

**My jars:**

- antlr-2.7.7
- byte-buddy-1.8.17
- classmate-1.3.4
- dom4j-2.1.1
- hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.4.Final
- hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final
- jandex-2.0.5.Final
- javassist-3.23.1-GA
- javax.activation-1.2.0
- javax.activation-api-1.2.0
- javax.persistence-api-2.2
- jaxb-api-2.3.0
- jaxb-core-2.3.0
- jaxb-impl-2.3.0
- jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final
- jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.1.1.Final
- jsp-api-2.2
- jstl-1.2
- mysql-connector-java-8.0.13
- protobuf-java-3.6.1
- servlet-api-2.5

Tomcat v9.0

**EmployeeHiberDAO.java**

```
package net.employeeregjdbc.dao;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import net.employeeregjdbc.controller.util.HibernateUtil;
import net.employeeregjdbc.model.Employee;



public class EmployeeHiberDAO {
    
    
    
    public void saveEmployee(Employee employee) {
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(employee);
            transaction.commit();
            
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (transaction != null ) transaction.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    
    
    public boolean validate(String username, String password) {
        Transaction transaction = null;
        Employee employee = null;
        
        try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            employee = (Employee) session.createQuery("FROM employee WHERE employee.username =:userNameQuery")
                    .setParameter("userNameQuery", username).uniqueResult();
            System.out.println(employee);
            if (employee != null && employee.getPassword().equals(password)) return true;
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (transaction != null ) transaction.rollback();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

**Employee.java**

```
package net.employeeregjdbc.model;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    public Employee() {
        super();
    }
    
    private static long searialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "note")
    private String note;
    
    
    public Employee(int id, String name, String username, String password, String note) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.note = note;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getNote() {
        return note;
    }
    public void setNote(String note) {
        this.note = note;
    }
    
}
```

**On console:**

```
Oct 01, 2023 1:37:45 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.7.Final}
Oct 01, 2023 1:37:45 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Hibernate java config service registry was created
Oct 01, 2023 1:37:46 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
Oct 01, 2023 1:37:46 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
Oct 01, 2023 1:37:46 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/j2ee_registration_employee_jdbc]
Oct 01, 2023 1:37:46 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=root}
Oct 01, 2023 1:37:46 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl buildCreator
INFO: HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Oct 01, 2023 1:37:46 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl$PooledConnections <init>
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Oct 01, 2023 1:37:47 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL55Dialect
Oct 01, 2023 1:37:48 PM org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl getIsolatedConnection
INFO: HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@54d13650] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
Oct 01, 2023 1:37:49 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl@1b79d968 is closed
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.errorIfClosed(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getConnectionForTransactionManagement(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.rollback(AbstractLogicalConnectionImplementor.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.rollback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:294)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:139)
    at net.employeeregjdbc.dao.EmployeeHiberDAO.validate(EmployeeHiberDAO.java:44)
    at net.employeeregjdbc.controller.EmployeeLoginHiber.authenticate(EmployeeLoginHiber.java:58)
    at net.employeeregjdbc.controller.EmployeeLoginHiber.doPost(EmployeeLoginHiber.java:49)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:696)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:891)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1784)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
```

Comment: Where are you calling `validate(username, password)` function? Also try to change query to `"FROM employee e WHERE e.username = :userNameQuery"`

Comment: Thank you. Problem was solved. I added `configuration.addAnnotatedClass(net.employeeregjdbc.model.Employee.class);` into HibernateUtil.java
Sorry for the lack of information provided